# How can I get a dynamic template working in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to build a "select" style directive that allows a template to be provided for each option but I'm struggling to get it working.  Here's what I have so far:

```
ngApp.directive('mySelect', function ($compile) {
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
    var template = element.html();
    var selectedItemTemplate = template.replace("item", "selectedItem");

    var html = "<div class='mySelect_selectedItem'>" + selectedItemTemplate + "</div>";
    html += "<div ng-repeat='item in items'><div class='mySelect_item' ng-click='onItemClicked(item)'>";
    html += template;
    html += "</div></div>";

    element = element.replaceWith($compile(html)(scope));

    scope.onItemClicked = function (item) {
        scope.selectedItem = item;
    };

    scope.selectedItemContainer = element.find(".mySelect_selectedItem");
    scope.itemContainers = element.find(".mySelect_item");
    scope.itemContainers.hide();
};

   return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        selectedItem: '=',
        items: '=',
    },
}
});
```

And usage would be something like:

```
<my-select items="things" selected-item="selectedThing">
<div>ITEM NAME: {{item.name}}</div>
</my-select>
```

Although on render I am getting what I would expect from my template, I can't seem to access the UI elements after the $compile, so the two jQuery selectors don't work.  I am guessing I need to call the $compile method somewhere else, or perhaps there is a much easier way of doing this?

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/q7DevKOm3tpgmvYpjqlR?p=info

Comment: set up a plunkr with what is working so far,it will be easier to debug.